# Changing "projects to build" field via Jenkins groovy console

Tags: groovy, jenkins, console

I'm trying to change the content of the "Projects to build/call" fields of a Jenkins job via the Groovy console.

I managed to find the field in the data structures but didn't find a method to change it.

Here is the code so far:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.getInstance().getView("v2.9").getItems().each { item ->
    Jenkins.getInstance().getItem(item.getName()).builders.each { builder ->
        if (builder.metaClass.respondsTo(builder, "getConfigs")) {
            builder.getConfigs().each { config ->
                println("projects to build: \"" + config.getProjects() + "\"")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how can I set back the values which are returned by `config.getProjects()` above. Something a-la `config.setProjects()` (which doesn't exist).

I'm using Jenkins v. 1.537

Thanks.